# Random image without repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, onclick, append

When I click on the image, the image changes randomly, but it happens that some images are repeated after the click. how can I solve it?

Below is my queue.

```
let h1 = document.querySelector('h1')
let bigSquare = document.createElement('div')
bigSquare.id = 'bigSquare'
h1.after(bigSquare)

let images = ['01.jpg', '02.jpg', '03.jpg', '04.jpg', '05.jpg']

let randomImage = function(){
   return (Math.round(Math.random()*(images.length-1)))
}

let image = document.createElement('img')
bigSquare.append(image)
image.src = images[randomImage()]

image.onclick = function(event){
   event.target.src = images[randomImage()]
}
```

Comment: shuffle the images array. declare an imageIndex variable initially set to 0. show shuffledImagesArray[imageIndex] and every time you click on the image increase imageIndex by 1 and set the source equal to shuffledImagesArray[imageIndex]. you can do this as many times as the images array length without getting a repeated image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a variable called say, `"randNumb"` that stores the random number generated in it and whenever the image is clicked, compare the previous random number with the new one and if they're different, change the img src else run the random image function again.

Check and run the following Code Snippet for a practical example of the above approach:

```js
let h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
let bigSquare = document.createElement('div');
let randNumb = 0;
bigSquare.id = 'bigSquare';
h1.after(bigSquare);

let images = ['01.jpg', '02.jpg', '03.jpg', '04.jpg', '05.jpg'];


let image = document.createElement('img');
bigSquare.append(image);
image.src = images[randNumb];

let randomImage = function(){

  let x = Math.round(Math.random()*(images.length-1)); // get random number
  
  if (x == randNumb) {
    randomImage(); // same random number so run function again
  } 
  else {
    randNumb = x;
    image.src = images[randNumb]; // not same random number so change src
    
    console.log("The image src right now is: " + image.src);
  }  
}

image.onclick = function(){randomImage()};
```

```html
<h1></h1>
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Cheers.